# Reading and comparing text file line

Tags: java, file

I have a simple login program and my very simple unsecure database is text file, which is this

```
mohammed
badpassword1
fahad
badpassword2
saad
Badpassword3
faisal
badpassword4
jack
badpasswod5
```

and I have this code reading every line in a text file and print it

I just want to pass the username and get it password which is the next line but I couldn't 
I tried to store it in array and get the password from next element from the username but all the elements are NULL, I don't know why 
can I get some help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("/Users/mohammed/Downloads/testFile.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line = new String();

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can used Properties file.

Comment: Reading files is done using **NIO** nowadays. Throw away your code and replace it by this line `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("myFile.txt"));`.

Comment: "I tried to store it in array" - I don't see that you tried any of that anywhere in your question. Why are you asking about code you don't have?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compare the line you currently read to the line you are looking for (username) and print the next one

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("/Users/mohammed/Downloads/testFile.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String username="mohammed";
    String line = new String();

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        if(line.equals(username){
            System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
            break;
        }

    reader.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: answer does not realise 'login' scenario. Speed run to SO reputation?

Comment: @jacek cz the question was how to compare a string right I guess to learn about strings and files? I dont think this code purpose is to make a real login

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a little stupid solution, but it should work.

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

....

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("/Users/mohammed/Downloads/testFile.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line = new String();

        // let's have this one to hold users
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

        int index = 1;
        User user = new User();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            now we will read line by line, create User objects and put them into the list
            System.out.println(line);
            if (index > 2) {
                // means you are reading the third line, so that's the name of the next user
                users.add(user); // save previous user
                user = new User(); // object to hold new one
                index = 1; // reset index
            }
            if (index == 1) {
                user.setUserName(line);
            }
            if (index == 2) {
                user.setPassword(line);
            }
            index++;
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // and once you have all the users in the list you can do whatever you need
   //e.g. print all users
   users.forEach(System.out::println);

   // find the user you need, e.g. with name 'fahad'
   final User fahad = users.stream().filter(u -> { return u.getUserName().equals("fahad")}).findFirst();
   System.out.println(fahad.getPassword()); // for instance
}
```